# Check CPU specs of other PC's on the domain in CMD

Tags: command-line, cpu

```
systeminfo /s srvmain
```

So I have used the above command in CMD to create a spreadsheet of each PC's specs in the domain. However, it doesn't give accurate CPU information. Is there a way to remotely find out what CPU a PC has on our domain? Some are located off-site via VPN so walking over and checking isn't an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did my answer work for you, or do you need any further help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Win32_Processor` WMI class and read that out via PowerShell

```
# Get Credentials of a Domain Account that has Admin Permission on RemoteComputers
$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential

# Declare list of Computers
$Computers = "Computer1", "Computer2", "Computer3"
# You could also read the Computers from a DC, play around with the -Filter
# $Computers = Invoke-Command -ComputerName DCServer { Get-ADComputer -Filter * } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Declare Properties you want to get (run Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | fl * to see all properties)
$Properties = "PSComputerName", "Name", "NumberOfCores"

# Create CIM Sessions
$CIM = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computers -Credential $AdminCredentials

# Run the command
$Result = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor -CimSession $CIM | Select-Object $Properties
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use [WMIC tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290216/a-description-of-the-windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-command-li).

To get everything about CPU you can call

```
wmic CPU GET /format:list
```

To get specific field, for example CPU name, you can call:

```
wmic CPU GET NAME /format:list
```

which will return something like

```
Name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

Which should be enough to obtain all other information eg. from Intel Ark database.

For querying remote machine with WMIC we have [related question on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/784513/how-to-use-wmic-to-connect-to-remote-machine-and-output-os-information-to-a-file) which boils down to:

```
wmic /NODE:"servername" /USER:"yourdomain\administrator" CPU GET NAME /format:list
```